# process.getprocessesbyname()

Tags: c#, process

I would like to use this function in C#, but I need to get 2 types of processes.
Is it possible to do something like this:
process.getprocessesbyname("process1", "process2");

How can I get the instances of 2 processes with different names?

TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var processes = GetProcesses(new[] { "name1", "name2", "explorer"});
}

public static IList<Process> GetProcesses(string[] processNames)
{
    var processes = new List<Process>(processNames.Length);
    foreach (var processName in processNames)
    {
        var namedProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        processes.AddRange(namedProcesses);
    }

    return processes;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IEnumerable<Process> processes =
    new[] { "process1", "process2" }
    .SelectMany(Process.GetProcessesByName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LINQ `Concat` method to concatenate the lists:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv")
    .Concat(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"));
```